# Cuda Program to Solve Pi

Tags: cuda, pi

I would like to know if there are any examples of solving for Pi using the trapezoidal rule in cuda.  I am trying to learn the language and I feel this would be a great way to gain knowledge on the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you google "cuda pi"?   Seems like a good way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PDF paper](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/cs653/10CUDA.pdf) with source-code and explanation.

*(found via google)*